# Arcane Disciple feat as a sorcerer and anyspell greater

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, sorcerer, domains

With the Spell Domain, can a Sorcerer utilize anyspell greater with the Arcane Disciple Feat?

Edit:
I think it should work, but Anyspell says: *Anyspell allows you **to read and prepare any arcane spell***

If I read it RAW, it says that the spell Allows it, but I have some doubts

Comment: Neat, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorcerers do not ordinarily have the ability to read or prepare spells; their class does not give them that ability like the wizard class does.

That doesn’t mean they *can’t* learn to do so somewhere else. The Arcane Preparation feat from *Complete Arcane* exists for exactly that purpose, it lets sorcerers and others who cast spells without preparation instead prepare some spells if they like. This avoids lengthening casting times when using metamagic, and may allow the character to meet certain requirements, like mage of the arcane order from the same book.

In the end, then, *anyspell* is just another way to learn how to read and prepare spells. Clerics can’t read spells from a spellbook normally, either. Same with sorcerers; this isn’t something they get from their class, but instead they get it from the spell and that’s fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!